# Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, events, variables, global, local

Why doesn't surveyName's value change?

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    surveyName = "catNull";
    function test(){
        window['surveyName'] = "catTest";
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input onclick = 'test()' id = 'cat' class = 'test' type = 'button' value = 'category' />

<script>
document.write('<input id = "survey" class = "test" type = "button" value = "'+surveyName+'" />');
</script>
```

Comment: It won't change until you click the button.

Comment: If a variable changes in a webpage, but no-one is there to see it, did it really change?

Comment: SLaks, you mean, JavaScript version of Shroedinger's cat? :)

Comment: What will happen here is a button will be written with a value "catNull", when you click it surveyName the variable changes, however that doesn't effect the input button's value. For that you would need something like document.getElementById('survey').value = "catTest";. JavaScript variables are not tied into the DOM automatically this way.

Answer (score 1):

It does change.

However, you never observe the change.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't change `input` object's value, only the variable.

The  element is independent of the variable.
If you want to change what the browser shows, you must do:

```
document.getElementById("...").value = window.surveyName;
```

Comment: Welcome. Here on stack overflow, you say "thank you" by clicking the UP arrow. Or the green check mark for a BIG thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not click on the input yet.

Answer (score 0):

It does. But you've already output the variable to the page, and what you've *output* doesn't change.

If you want to change the `input`'s value:

```
document.getElementById("survey").value = "new value";
```

That works because you've assigned the element the `id` value `"survey"`, so you can retrieve the element via [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) passing in that `id`, and use the element's [`value` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-221662474) to set the value.